# Dnsmasq white list for specific clients on network

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

I'd like to use dnsmasq to set up a white list for certain clients on my network.

For instance, I'd like to have these rules for clients in the range 192.168.1.10 - 192.168.1.20:

```
no-resolv
server=/pbskids.org/192.168.0.1
server=/disney.go.com/192.168.0.1
```

This way, the only websites accessible from these clients are the ones that are whitelisted. Clients on the network outside of that range should be able to use whatever DNS server they want. How can I do this?

**EDIT:**

This is what I have in dnsmasq.conf so far:

```
bogus-priv
domain-needed
no-resolv

server=/pbskids.org/192.168.0.1
server=/disney.go.com/192.168.0.1
```

This has the intended result of denying upstream DNS lookups to all clients on the network. Now what I need is a way to allow certain clients to use upstream DNS instead. I don't think an option like this exists but maybe it will help get my idea across:

```
use-resolv --source 192.168.1.150
```

i.e., if the client's IP address is 192.168.1.150 then use upstream DNS servers. Alternatively, what I was originally looking for was something like this:

```
no-resolv --source 192.168.1.100
```

i.e., if the client's IP address is 192.168.1.100 then don't use upstream servers at all.

If I can't do something like this, then maybe what I need is two separate networks.

Comment: This sounds like what you want: http://www.teknynja.com/2009/06/to-protect-and-surf-dnsmasq-and.html

Comment: That's where I started :)

Answer (score 5):

This tutorial sounds like what you want. Titled: [To Protect and Surf (dnsmasq and Whitelists)](http://www.teknynja.com/2009/06/to-protect-and-surf-dnsmasq-and.html).

The idea is fairly simple. Isolate machines so that their only DNS server they're aware of is the DNSMasq server. Then add the following lines to DNSMasq's config. file, `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
domain-needed
bogus-priv
log-queries
log-facility=/var/log/dnsmasq.log
no-resolv
interface=eth0

# Add other name servers here, with domain specs if they are for
# non-public domains.
#server=/localnet/192.168.0.1
server=/google.com/192.168.0.1
server=/dan-dare.org/192.168.0.1
server=/dan-dare.net/192.168.0.1
server=/pbskids.org/192.168.0.1
server=/playhousedisney.com/192.168.0.1
server=/disney.go.com/192.168.0.1
server=/starfall.com/192.168.0.1
```

Once you have this in place the servers pointing to the DNSMasq server will simply not be able to find any DNS results besides the ones in the config. file.

**NOTE:** This is by no means full proof and can be circumvented pretty easily. But if you're using it to keep children off of other websites, then it's probably enough for the task.

#### DNS

You can setup a system so that its DNS is configured to only send requests to the DNSMasq server through the configuration file, `/etc/resolv.conf`.

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: How do I "Isolate machines so that their only DNS server they're aware of is the DNSMasq server"?

Comment: @davidkennedy85 - depends on how your network is setup, but the easiest method would be to edit the `/etc/resolv.conf` file and add the IP of the dnsmaq server.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a way to enforce local policies like that. I need a way to force nameservers at the proxy level, if that makes sense.

Comment: @davidkennedy85 - can you explain the situation more then? Ultimately the solution, if any, is going to hinge on how you have your environment setup. Try and focus on the computers and how they're accessing the internet. Do they use DHCP? Is there a single computer doing NAT in a home network or is this a business?

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to get back to you, I got distracted. Let's just say I have a wireless hotspot, and I don't want just anyone who jumps on the network to be able to access whatever they want. Certain clients should be able to however. At this point I'm thinking that I need two separate networks unfortunately, which most likely means investing in extra hardware. It would be cool if dnsmasq could handle this but if not then oh well.

Comment: @davidkennedy85 - 2 networks would likely be the best path. But depending on your DHCP server setup, you could potentially config. it so that there were 2 groups of hosts. GroupA would get DNS server info X and GroupB would get DNS server info Y. This would be very loosely enforceable, so a person in the know could easily thwart it by manually setting their DNS server, but it would give you some of what you're asking for.

Comment: That's not really a problem since I can block DNS requests (port 53) with iptables.

Comment: @DavidKennedy I know this is much much later, but I decided to run 2 instances of dnsmasq in docker containers... I set one up, as a DNS only server as described above, and other one as a regular DNS forwarder and DHCP server. On this latter one I used "tags" to selectively set the DNS server for my kids devices to be different to the "adult" devices via mac address. works well (until they figure out how to set 8.8.8.8 on the client as a DNS server)